# How do I make DataFrames, which names are taken from the list of names?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am exploring basics of pandas and I am working on an assignment that I've found.

I have created a list, which contains names for future DataFrames in Pandas. 
That's the list:

```
DF_names_by_year = ['year_1985', 'year_1986', 'year_1987', ..., 'year_2010', 'year_2011', 'year_2012', 'year_2013']
```

I have a big df with information regarding each year from the list. Now I have to make a graph to show some of the information in each year. I want to group the df by year and cut it and give each new df name appropriately from the list of names.

It works if I type the name:

```
year_1985 = pd.DataFrame(teams_wins_salaries.loc[teams_wins_salaries['yearID'] == 1985])
```

but if I put it into a loop, I actually make a list of empty dataframes.

```
for i in range(len(DF_names_by_year)):
    DF_names_by_year[i] = pd.DataFrame(teams_wins_salaries.loc[teams_wins_salaries['yearID'] == i])
```

```
[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [yearID, teamID, W, salary]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [yearID, teamID, W, salary]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [yearID, teamID, W, salary]
```

My intuition tells me that there should be a way to separate the df and give a name to each part. I only wonder if it is possible to give them names from the list.

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to solve the problem.

Comment: The dataframes are empty because `[i]` in your list is the string;`'year_1985'`, but your df contains the years as ints; `1985`. Maybe `['yearID'] == int(i.split('_')[1])]`?

Comment: At the same time, I question if you want that many individual dataframes to begin with. Can you not just do `teams_wins_salaries.groupby('yearID').mean()` (or `.count(),.sum()` etc)?

Comment: I can't use .mean or .sum, because I have two data sets (wins and salaries) for 25 teams for each year, and I have to plot it into a graph. These are different data to compare and present on graph. Because there is a lot of data to plot at the same time, I want to separate it at least into graphs for each year.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `groupby` to split your data frame by all unique years. Also, consider using a list or dictionary of data frames instead of flooding your global envirobment with many similar-structured objects.

```
# LIST COMPREHENSION
year_df_list = [g for i,g in teams_wins_salaries.groupby('yearID')]

# DICTIONARY COMPREHENSION
year_df_dict = {i:g for i,g in teams_wins_salaries.groupby('yearID')}
```

You lose no functionality of the data frame if it is stored in a list or dict. So instead of maintaining 30+ separate, isolated, named global items you maintain *one* that can be traversed, looped, graphed easily and harmoniously:

```
year_df_list[1]·head()
year_df_list[2].describe()
year_df_list[3].shape

year_df_dict['1985']·head()
year_df_dict['1990'].describe()
year_df_dict['1995'].shape
```